# how do I automatically run a php script after mysql timestamp is 1 month ago?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run a script to end a listing on my local classified ads site when the listing has been online for 1 month. The site is written in PHP using a MySQL database.

How do I use the timestamp to do this?

Comment: erm, if the PHP script consists of just some MySQL queries, you can try event-scheduler in MySQL.

Comment: Why don't you just add a `WHERE` clause to your queries?  E.g. `WHERE listing_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`.

Comment: And Presumably you're running a CRON-job for it :)

Comment: @eggyal A good suggestion, but do you see any value in perhaps having the listing an an *explicitly* ended state, instead of its endedness being derived from another value?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: Not especially.  One would still need to filter records based on that other value.  Indexes would pretty much eliminate any performance difference.

Comment: @eggyal Right, but what if the rules for derivation change? What if the listing now spans 2 months? What if, down the line, he wants different listing types with different durations? Should that necessitate changing the query? Also, what if he still wants to display ended listings? Comparing a bit field to determine how to display something must be more efficient than comparing dates, no?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: What if he wants to convert the prices into other currencies?  What if he wants to translate the entire website?  What if he wants to calculate shipping costs to the moon?  What if he wants to magic pixies to sprinkle all of his customers with fairy dust?  What if...   I think it's probably best to stay within the scope of the question.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: Sorry, that was probably a bit unfair :) I think an `expiry_date` column would address most of your points, then select `WHERE expiry_date >= CURDATE()` for unexpired records and `WHERE expiry_date < CURDATE()` for expired ones.

Comment: Apology accepted (though I did flag it, simply because it is a bit rude, so if you like, feel free to delete). That aside, *this* is a better suggestion. There is a fixed piece of data (instead of a derivation), *and* it avoids the need for an auxiliary job to run and expire a listing.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want `MySQL` to push you some information, a possibility if to create an [UDF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html) function called by a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). Take a look, you will see if it's overkill or not.

Comment: i want to change column 'closed' from 0 to 1 after 1 month